# fading popup using jquery mobile on a phonegap app

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I've got a popup invoked as following:

```
$( "#popupid" ).popup("open");
```

which is something like:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popupId" class="ui-content">
</div>
```

is it possible to make it fade in and fade out automatically?
I'm using jQuery Mobile on a PhoneGap app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just simple:

add this in HTML

`data-transition="fade"`

like this

```
<div data-role="popup" data-transition="fade" id="popupId" class="ui-content">
</div>
```

then do your logic for your automatic `popup('open')` and `popup('close')`

It Works 100%